# Value of the product: $ \sqrt{2} \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}} \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}}} \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}} \cdots $ =?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, infinite-product, nested-radicals

Let the recursive sequence
$$ a_0 = 0, \qquad a_{n+1} = \sqrt{2-a_n},\,\,n\in\mathbb N.
$$
T
Can we find the value of the product
$$
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}?
$$

Well, from here I don't seem to follow. I can understand that there would be some good simplification and the product will hopefully telescope but I'm lacking the right algebra. I also thought of finding a recurrence solution probably from the corresponding DE but that didn't follow as well.

Comment: have you tried to take the logarithm?

Comment: Yes, I tried. But it too didn't seem to help much.

Comment: Have you tried first to find $(\prod a_n)^2$ ?

Comment: Wolfram Mathematica says $\prod_{n=1}^{1000}a_n\approx 1.1547005383792515290183\ldots$

Comment: @vrugtehagel, [ISC](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/standard) thinks that's $(3/4)^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Originally, it is taken from [here](http://people.missouristate.edu/lesreid/Adv187.html)

Comment: Set $a_n=2\cos\phi_n$, then $\sqrt{2-a_n}=2\sin\frac{\phi_n}{2}=2\cos\frac{\pi-\phi_n}{2}$. Now since $\phi_{n+1}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\phi_n}{2}$, the solution for $\phi_n$ is
$$\phi_n=\frac{\pi}{3}\left[1-\left(-\frac12\right)^{n+1}\right].$$ Thus even the finite product presumably telescopes.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Squaring the infinite product we observe that
$$
2(2-\sqrt{2})\big(2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}\big)\Big(2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}\Big)\cdots\\ =
2\cdot\frac{2}{2+\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}
\cdot\frac{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}}\cdots \\
=\frac{4}{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\cdots}}}}
$$
But
$$
\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\cdots}}}}= 1.
$$
See: [Convergence of $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2-a_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1640379/convergence-of-the-recursive-sequence-a-n1-sqrt2-a-n/1640420#1640420). Thus
$$
2(2-\sqrt{2})\big(2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}\big)\Big(2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}\Big)\cdots = \frac{4}{3}
$$
Finally
$$
\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}\sqrt{(2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}}\cdots = \sqrt{\frac{4}{3}}
$$

Comment: Where did $4$ come from? I'm not sure I get it

Comment: @YuriyS All the terms in the numerator will simplify except for the first one, and the coefficient $2$. So you get $2\cdot 2 = 4$

Answer (score 15):

Another approach is the following one: if we assume $ a_n = 2\cos(\theta_n) $ it follows that
$$ \cos(\theta_{n+1})=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\theta_n}{2}} = \sin\left(\frac{\theta_n}{2}\right) = \cos\left(\frac{\pi-\theta_n}{2}\right)\tag{1} $$
from which we have $\theta_{n+1}=\frac{\pi-\theta_n}{2}$ and, by induction:
$$ \theta_{n+k} = \frac{\pi}{3}-(-1)^k\frac{\pi}{3\cdot 2^k}+(-1)^k\frac{\theta_n}{2^k}.\tag{2}$$
Since $\theta_0=\frac{\pi}{2}$,
$$ \theta_k = \frac{\pi}{3}+(-1)^k \frac{\pi}{6\cdot 2^k},\qquad \color{red}{a_k = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6\cdot 2^k}\right)-(-1)^k\sqrt{3}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6\cdot 2^k}\right)}\tag{3} $$
but since $2\cos\theta_n = \frac{\sin(2\theta_n)}{\sin(\theta_n)}$ and $\sin(\pi-\theta)=\sin(\theta)$, we also have a telescopic product.

In particular:
$$ a_1\cdot a_2\cdot\ldots\cdot a_n = \frac{\sin(2\theta_1)}{\sin(\theta_n)} \tag{4}$$
hence:

> $$ \prod_{n\geq 1} a_n = \frac{\sin(2\theta_1)}{\sin(\lim_{n\to +\infty}\theta_n)} = \frac{1}{\sin\frac{\pi}{3}}=\color{red}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}}.\tag{5}$$

Comment: It's fascinating to me how closely this method parallels evaluating the Viete product, and yet how different the final result is.

Comment: This is a general method and that makes it really helpful. What if we didn't have a $2$ even. What if we had some $k$?

Comment: How did you proceed from (3) to the red statement?

Comment: @zz20s: by just computing twice the cosine of a difference through the cosine addition formulas.

Comment: Ah! I see it now, thank you.